# Having problem to map USA state map with SF and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I have some points (lat and long) like this:

```
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
Latitude = sample(31:46, size = 300, replace = TRUE)
Longitude = sample(-80:-120, size = 300, replace = TRUE)
df = data.frame(Latitude, Longitude)
```

To map this, I have a code like this:

## code1

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

usa <- st_as_sf(maps::map("state", fill=TRUE, plot =FALSE))

ggplot(usa) +
  geom_sf(color = "#2b2b2b", fill = "royalblue", size=0.125) +
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs("+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs"), datum = NA)+
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude))
```

However, the outcome does not show the points correctly[image]

I can plot it with this code but I am looking for a map like the above code to have a curve map

## code 2

```
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")


ggplot(data = world) +
    geom_sf() +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(-67.74, -125.55), ylim = c(25, 50), expand = FALSE)+geom_point(data = df, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude))
```

Could you please fix the code1.

Comment: Lat 45, Long -100 is exactly what the map is showing you.

Comment: Yes how can I adjust for the actual maps?

Comment: add the argument `default_crs = st_crs(4326)`, check out the docs `?geom_sf`

Comment: Thank you , the output is the same by code 2. It is not curve.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn your *df* into *sf* object and plot points with another `geom_sf()` layer:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
Latitude = sample(31:46, size = 300, replace = TRUE)
Longitude = sample(-80:-120, size = 300, replace = TRUE)
df = data.frame(Latitude, Longitude) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = "WGS84")

usa <- st_as_sf(maps::map("state", fill=TRUE, plot =FALSE))

ggplot(usa) +
  geom_sf(color = "#2b2b2b", fill = "royalblue", size=0.125) +
  geom_sf(data = df) +
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs("+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs"), datum = NA)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>